# How do I identify a blended layer in iOS?

Tags: ios, debugging, uiview-hierarchy

I am triggering an iOS animation to move some elements around on my screen, and when I do so, an area at the bottom of the screen (away from where I *think* I'm doing the operation) changes shade slightly.  When I turn on 'show blended layers' in the iPhone simulator, it's clear that at the beginning of my animation, *something* starts overlaying that area, but I cannot figure out what.  The view that I'm adding to my screen is a composite view, including a scrollview and an overlay -- something in there is overflowing the bounds it should be in, and I can't figure out what.  The simulator obviously knows what it is -- it's happy to color it red for me as a blended layer -- but I can't get it to tell me *what* layer is being blended so I can fix it.  How do I do this?

ETA: If I turn on clipsToBounds on the inserted view, my problem goes away.  But I'd still like to know how to identify layered views when I'm trying to debug.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try animating it all, but each time hide one more subview until one moment, when a subview is removed and problem is no longer visible - You will know which view is faulty.

Better is to go   [view subviews]  - to really access them all.